# Training Streams on Brain,js?

Tags: javascript, brain.js

I'm using brain.js for a discord bot, but I'm having a serious problem. The complete training uses the 100% of my thread (as I'm using Javascript) and even doing it async stops all my bot. I read about something called **TrainingStream** **(example at the bottom)** on the brain.js documentation, but I wasn't able to find out the solution.

The perfect solution would be to be able to add Training Data to the original training (as it trains the brain when the app starts). Something like if I have some data on the memory, add more training to that memory without having to retrain all the bot.

Thanks.

```
const brain = require('brain.js');

const net = new brain.NeuralNetwork();
const xor = [
  { input: [0, 0], output: [0] },
  { input: [0, 1], output: [1] },
  { input: [1, 0], output: [1] },
  { input: [1, 1], output: [0] },
];

function readInputs(stream, data) {
  for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    stream.write(data[i]);
  }
  // let it know we've reached the end of the inputs
  stream.endInputs();
}

const trainingStream = new brain.TrainStream({
  neuralNetwork: net,
  /**
   * Write training data to the stream. Called on each training iteration.
   */
  floodCallback: function () {
    readInputs(trainingStream, xor);
  },

  /**
   * Called when the network is done training.
   */
  doneTrainingCallback: function (obj) {
    console.log(
      `trained in ${obj.iterations} iterations with error: ${obj.error}`
    );

    const result01 = net.run([0, 1]);
    const result00 = net.run([0, 0]);
    const result11 = net.run([1, 1]);
    const result10 = net.run([1, 0]);

    console.log('0 XOR 1: ', result01); // 0.987
    console.log('0 XOR 0: ', result00); // 0.058
    console.log('1 XOR 1: ', result11); // 0.087
    console.log('1 XOR 0: ', result10); // 0.934
  },
});

// kick it off
readInputs(trainingStream, xor);
```

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why would you train the bot each time it is started? You could train it once and then save the model?

Comment: @Kokodoko so the bot on start it is trained and saves that model, but the things is that they could add new information, and that new information should be trained another time, so when I want to add that new information to the bot's memory, the problem is that I have to train another time the full bot and it uses the 100% of the thread, so I need to make that process on another VPS (idk how) or in such a way put more information to the memory without training the full bot another time.

Comment: Sometimes you can just keep adding data to an already trained model, and then retrain it. You don’t need to keep the original data and train the same model every time. But I’m not sure if brain.js allows this. You can always try!

Comment: @Kokodoko Which library allows that?

Comment: Brain.js allows loading a trained model from a JSON file: https://github.com/BrainJS/brain.js#json

Comment: @Kokodoko I think that using a custom API and exporting/importing the trianing model I'll be able to do it, lot of thanks <3

Comment: Maybe the thing you're looking for is the workers in JavaScript: https://nodejs.org/api/worker_threads.html#worker-threads